# Postgresql: out of shared memory due to max locks per transaction using temporary table

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables, locks

I am using Postgresql 9.6. 
I have a stored proc which is called by Scala. This stored proc is a wrapper, i.e. it will call another stored procs for each input list passed in wrapper. For e.g. wrapper has input list of 100 elements, so the internal stored proc will be called 100 times per element.
The internal proc is data heavy proc, which creates 4-5 temp tables and processes the data and returns.
So wrapper will collect all the data and finally complete.

```
get_data_synced(date, text, integer[])
```

Here the text is comma-separated items (10-1000 depending on use -case).

Basically the problem is if I pass a bigger number 100-200 items i.e. in a loop we call the internal procs that many times, it throws the error:

```
SQL execution failed (Reason: ERROR: out of shared memory
Hint: You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
```

I understand that create temp table inside the internal function will create locks. Bu each time the proc is called, first thing is DROP and then CREATE the temp table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _temp_data_1;
CREATE TEMP TABLE _temp_data_1 AS (...);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _temp_data_2;
CREATE TEMP TABLE _temp_data_2 AS (...);

..
..
..
```

So even if the proc is called 1000 times, the first thing it does is drop table (which should release locks?) and then create the table.

The max_locks_per_transaction is set to 256.

Now, the transaction is not over until my wrapper function (outside function) is over, right? 
So it means that even if I am dropping the temp table, the locks are not released?

Is there a way to release the lock on temp table immediately once my function is complete?

Answer (score 2):

You diagnosis is correct, the locks survive until the end of the transaction.  Even if it was dropped in the same transaction that created it, and even if it is a temp table.  Perhaps this could be optimized, but that is currently how it works.

For work-arounds, why not just truncate the table, rather than drop and re-create it, if it already exists?